# How Xcode deal with universal lib when archiving ipa?

Tags: xcode, static-libraries

I have an universal static lib which includes iphoneos and simulator arch. When I archive an ipa for appsotre, Xcode will remove the simulator part or not? It confuses me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Archiving will not remove the simulator part. If you want to reduce the size of the ipa, you can only use the static lib which includes iphoneos when archiving.